# Как вывести математические задачки из списка так, чтобы пайтон выводил не решение этих задач, а саму задачу

Tags: python

```
task = [2 + 2 * 2,
        30 * 32,
        150 // 3 * 3,
        2 ** 2 + 3 ** 2,
        2 ** 5
        ]
print(task)
```

Comment: Кавычки поставь

Answer (score 3):

Для корректного отображения математических задач, их следует записывать в текстовом формате. Это означает, что каждый элемент списка должен быть заключён в кавычки. Это обеспечит правильное представление математических выражений.

```
task = ['2 + 2 * 2',
        '30 * 32',
        '150 // 3 * 3',
        '2 ** 2 + 3 ** 2',
        '2 ** 5'
        ]
print(task)
```